# problems with regex url validator

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex to test if a url is valid or not. I had a good [example](https://www.regextester.com/94502) to work off of, but I had to tweak it a bit to make it fit my purpose:

```
^(https?:\/\/)(www\.)?(\w*\.)+([\w\-_~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.])*$
```

It works fine for the most part, but it matches the following, which drives me nuts:

```
http://www..example..com
```

I tried forever and I just can't get the magical combination of characters to get it to ignore the above use case. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a list of things I want the regex to match (all of them are matched):

```
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/
https://example.com/
https://blog.example.com/
https://my.blog.example.com/
https://my.blog.example.co.uk/
https://www.example.com/#test
https://www.example.com#test
https://www.example.com/test.php
https://www.example.com/test.php?test=yes&testmore=yesevenmore
https://www.example.com/test.php#test
https://www.example.com/test.php?test=yes&testmore2=yesevenmore&whatnumber=42#test
https://www.example.com/test
https://www.example.com/test/
https://www.example.com/test/?test=yes&testmore2=yesevenmore&whatnumber=42
https://www.example.com/test/#test
https://www.example.com/test/?test=yes&testmore=yesevenmore&whatnumber=42#test
https://www.example.com/test/?test=yes&testmore=yesevenmore&whatnumber=42#test
https://www.blog.example.com/test/?test=yes&testmore=yesevenmore&whatnumber=42#test
https://www.my.blog.example.com/test/?test=yes&testmore=yesevenmore&whatnumber=42#test
https://my.blog.example.co.uk/?test=yes&testmore=yesevenmore&whatnumber=42#test
http://255.255.255.255
http://www.example.com:8008
http://www.example.com:8008/test/?test=yes&testmore=yesevenmore&whatnumber=42#test
```

Here's a list of things I DON'T want it to match:

```
www.example.com
example.com
*http://www.blog..example..com
*http://www..example.com
*http://www...example.com
*http://www..example..com
http://www.example.com | not valid
http://www.example.com|
255.255.255.255
```

* still matched

How can I prevent regex from matching the multidots?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^https?:\/\/(?:[-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+\.)*[-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+$` https://regex101.com/r/dF8zpI/1

Comment: Just try to connect to the site and check the return status.

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, thank you!!! That works for my use cases...

Comment: I think `^https?:\/\/(?:[^\s.|]+\.)*[^\s.|]+$` is what you need: only allow non-consecutive dots, no `|` and spaces in the URLs. See https://regex101.com/r/74BCXB/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Might be a bit too specific, I only want valid characters in the after domain part, so I don't really want to search for a specific character like `|` to check if it's there or not.

Comment: Try `^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(?:[:/#][-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.]*)?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/HCB0Qt/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern matches the dot literally `\.` as well as in the character class which is repeated 1+ times as a group and `(\w*\.)+` also matches consecutive dots.

You could shorten the character class as some parts do not have to be escaped and `\w` also matches `_`

Using the characters from your character class that you accept to be valid you could repeat in a group matching what you want to allow excluding the dot and match a single dot at the end:

```
^https?:\/\/(?:[-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+\.)*[-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+$
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `https?:\/\/` Match http:// or https://
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+\.` Match 1+ times any of listed, then match a `.`
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `[-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+` Match any of the listed 1+ times (note that there is no `.`)
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dF8zpI/1)

A more specific variant:

```
^https?:\/\/\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?:[/#:][-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.]*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jDpE9P/1)

Comment: I think it's a good solution, but there is one flaw: you don't want to use the same character set for the domain part as for the rest of the URL, otherwise garbage like `http://ww?w.example.com` will be matched. I tried `^https?:\/\/(\w+.)*[-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+$` and `^https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+.)*[-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+$`, but they still match the ? for some reason...

Comment: @SynnKo You did not escape the dot.

Comment: @SynnKo A more specific pattern could be `^https?:\/\/\w+(?:\.\w+)*(?:[/#:][-\w~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.]*)?$`  https://regex101.com/r/jDpE9P/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Right, forgot the dot... wouldn't have worked anyway, some of the previously matched test cases were no longer being matched. Your solution works like a charm, though! Many thanks.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Small correction: the first * needs to be changed to a +, otherwise it will match stuff like http://www.